# Logical condition in set (GAMS) - how do this in pyomo?

Tags: set, conditional-statements, pyomo, gams-math

I'm passing code from Gams to pyomo and I don't know if this option to access an index has in python.

In gams:

> k purifiers /PSA4241, PSA241, PSA241A, PSA3241, NEW/
>
> oldk(k)    = yes$(ord(k) le 4) ; newk(k)    = yes$(ord(k) eq 5) ;
>
> EL31(i,k,s)$newk(k)..   zkns(k,s) =g= ZIK(i,k,s);

$newk(k) it would just be a part of the set k.
How could I use this selection in pyomo? Any tips?

Comment: Hi, Patricia. Can you please specify the desire output? I don't understand what do you want to do

Comment: k is a set with 5 elements, but I would only like to access the 5 element for that equation, so I separated it into two subsets, the first 4 I called oldk and the last one would be newk.
In gams you have the logical conditions, for example, that restriction would be calculated only for that subset newk.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your question and comments, what I understand is: You got a full `Set` (lest call it S) in a `ConcreteModel()` in pyomo and you need, to use just a slice of that `Set` (lets call it S1) in order to use it into a `Constraint`. Your approach is just creating a couple of `Sets` such that `S = S1∪S2` to use it as you want.

In `pyomo` for the constraint you can do that, or you can just pass the value you want into the `Constraint`

Lets assume a problem structure:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

mySet = ['m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5']
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.s = pyo.Set(initialize=mySet)
model.x = pyo.Var(model.s, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
```

If you want to apply a certain constraint just to the final value of the set, you can just pass it into one single constraint, like this

```
model.const = pyo.Constraint(expr=model.x[model.s[-1]]>=5)
```

or you can use the `last()` method of the `OrderedSimpleSet` class

```
model.const = pyo.Constraint(expr=model.x[model.s.last()]>=5)
```

In the same way you can use the `indexedConstraint` approach to apply the same structure to several values.

```
def constr2(model, s):
    return model.x[s] >= 5
model.constr2 = pyo.Constraint(model.s.ordered_data()[-2:], )
```

This will apply the constraint to the last 2 values of the Set.

If you definitely need to split your original data, you can create a first new set and then apply the `difference` method to generate the rest values

```
model.s2 = pyo.Set(initialize=['m1','m2'])
model.s1 = model.s.difference(model.s2)
```

This will give you this result

```
>>>model.s1.display()
s1 : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=True
    Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
    None :     1 : s - s2 :    3 : {'m3', 'm4', 'm5'}
>>>model.s2.display()
s2 : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
    Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
    None :     1 :    Any :    2 : {'m1', 'm2'}
```

I hope this help you to understand how you can deal with slicing `Set` in `pyomo` and why using a programming language as Python can improve the performance of a modeling task.